# How to use Android's built-in icons

Tags: android, android-drawable

I want to use Android's built in icons, I don't know how, I tried to use this two lines:

```
    android:background="@drawable/ic_lock_silent_mode_off"

    android:background="R.drawable.ic_lock_silent_mode_off"
```

Both lines aren't working for me, how can I use this icon to my button?

I get this error:

```
error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'background' with value '@drawable/ic_lock_silent_mode_off').
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

With that, you are trying to reference your own drawable, not Android's.

You need to use:

```
android:background="@android:drawable/ic_lock_silent_mode_off"
```

Comment: Oh and another question, do you know if there is Android drawable icon for shop or store? I want to create a shop to my app and I don't really know how to make my own icon and at the internet they are not that pretty..

Comment: But don't do this for versions < 4.0 because you are not guaranteed that Holo theme exists therefor the icons could be styled however the OEM wanted them to be styled. What you can do instead is copy them from the SDK/res folder into your project so you can get a consistent look and feel.

Comment: for reference, here's [Google's doc on iconography](http://developer.android.com/design/style/iconography.html#menuapx) and [the download link](http://developer.android.com/design/downloads/index.html) to get the standard theme icons